# Rails Thread Starvation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, memory-leaks, rake

I am currently working on an IMAP service that pulls a sliding window of users' emails from Gmail and stores them locally for performance reasons. Transferring, decoding and storing emails works, but the threads idling through the IMAP IDLE command are experiencing difficulties in staying alive.

What happens? The threads are started by running a rake task, with one thread per user. This is working fine, and I am restarting problematic threads if the IMAP IDLE signal is lost, the connection reset or the threads die. But the code seems to be causing a memory leak or something else, leading to thread starvation. In other words, threads are successfully identified as being dead since the IMAP IDLE signal is not received, but when I try to restart them, the threads won't execute themselves.

More specifically, memory usage is increasing from **64 MiB to >300 MiB** within a few days, potentially causing thread starvation. I am not sure about this, though. When debugging with fewer threads (15 users only = 15 threads, plus 15 extra threads in the Ruby IMAP library) on a staging machine, and counting objects created, only a negligible increase in memory use could be identified.

My questions therefore are... ;)

- How to debug this properly?
- Does Ruby have a problem with thread starvation? We also tried JRuby, but to no avail.
- And is anyone else experiencing or has anyone else experienced similar problems?

Comment: Not very clear with your problem, but as I known any platform always supports a limited number of threads. Thread starvation will come if we abuse of using thread, not only in Ruby, but also in Java. Do you use ThreadPool to manage threads?

Comment: Threads in Ruby (MRI 1.9.x) are still not native to the operating system. Are 220 threads already too much? Also, this happens only after more than one day of working perfectly. Since threads need to idle, how could I use thread pools?

Answer (score 0):

That is a long shot, but if you suspect, that your code or some library leaks threads or memory, you can try [Plumbr](http://plumbr.eu) with JRuby version of your application. Plumbr is mainly targeted to finding memory leaks in Java application, but we have some success stories with JVM-based languages as well.